# Azure login for admins

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure with several other colleagues.
We have a shared admin account which all of us have access to (credentials).
A few days ago when trying to login in azure portal with the admin account we got this message: "More information required. YOur organization needs more information to keep your account secure.".
And than it asks me to select an authentication mode: authenticator app, phone, email.

As we use the same account for admin purposes, for 5 people, what would be the best way to deal with this?

Comment: How about not using one account? This is an honest comment, not meant to be mean or something

Comment: One admin account for each user?

Comment: Yes indeed. There is no extra cost involved.

Comment: I know but we use non admin users. And have only a admin user for security reasons

Comment: But if the non admin users have access to admin credentials then why not make those 5 users admin? Or even better, give them only the roles that are needed to perform their work

Comment: Otherwise one person gets the authentication request on their phone/mail/app if anyone wants to access azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment like below:***

When the  **MFA is enabled for the user**, it results in the below screen:

[image]

MFA strengthens the security of the admin account. This prevents the unauthorized user access.

If you want admin account to be secured with 2 step verification, then you can configure the authentication method based on requirement (either phone or Email or Authenticator App).

**Otherwise**, I agree with @Peter Bons creating individual admin accounts for each user would be the best solution.

[image]

- By ensuring that each user has their own set of credentials and access privileges, this can help to increase security.
- Based on the individual, MFA can be enabled.
- This improves the security and unauthorized access too.

**Reference:**

[azure-docs/security-planning.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/roles/security-planning.md)